# Android how do I get a Tween Animation to use Animator duration scale in the developer settings?

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

We have been turning off animations to run UI tests using the developer settings. We are using support fragments and the support fragment manager to setCustomAnimations which do not adhere to the scale that is set in the developer settings. 
I found some documentation that the objectAnimators will use the scale settings in but the support fragments don't support animators for the animations.

Is there a way to create create xml animations that adhere to the developer settings with the support fragments?